# Endmarks not showing up, thmmarks, ntheorem

Tags: theorems

I can't get thmmarks in ntheorem to work in Latex.

I've tried searching around the web, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I suspect there's something simple I'm missing. Here's a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
%
%
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{ex}
This is my example. It's an example of an example \dots
\[
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \; \text{dx}
\]
\end{ex}
\end{document}
```

I tried recompiling ntheorem.sty to no avail.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is not showing any end mark. If you want one, you have to explicitly specify which symbol you want as end mark.

```
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
```

(Afterwards you need to compile twice.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that, the documentation is pretty unclear.