# How can I insert a symbol when a definition or an example or a sentence finish?

Tags: symbols, theorems

I searched the solution. I tried the `declaretheorem` command but my TeXstudio couldn't read it.

Comment: It's easy to automatically insert a symbol at the end of any theorem structure with  package `ntheorem`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please provide your best take on the wonderful tested and proven minimum working example (MWE).

Comment: Bernard, i want it automatically.

Null, for example in many mathematical reports in the end of proofs there is the symbol \square. How can i define a command which write a symbol automatically in the end of definition or example etc?

Comment: this might help: [Endmarks not showing up, thmmarks, ntheorem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11573/579)